# How do you do axios error handling in React (for user authentication)?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, error-handling, axios, react-hooks

I am trying to implement user authentication in Context.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import config from './config/config'
import axios from 'axios'
const Context = React.createContext()

function ContextProvider({children}) {

    const authenticate = async (email, password) => {
        let e = null;
        axios.post(
            `${config.url}/auth/login`,
            JSON.stringify({email, password}),
            { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
        ).then(function (response) {
            //save token
            //save user
            //redirect to app home
        }).catch( error => {
            e = error
        })
        return e
    }

    return(
        <Context.Provider value={{authenticate}}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}

export {ContextProvider, Context}
```

and then call it with useContext Hook in Login.js component.

```
export default function Login() {
const context = useContext(Context)
const [errors, setErrors] = useState(null)
const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

const loginUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const axiosErrors = context.authenticate(email, password)
    console.log(axiosErrors)
```

Although I am able to capture the errors / in the catch { console.log(e) } block of the axios call, I am unable to capture them in Login.js.
Thus, the above console.log, logs the following to the console:

```
{axiosErrors: Promise}
POST http://localhost:7000/api/auth/login 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Comment: Why don't you try/catch in your Login component? You can handle error state in catch block then

Comment: @tmhao2005 thanks for the idea, I could do that. Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Or you can also try/catch in your `authenticate` itself then you would return a status to be false. Then you just simply get the result of the function in your `Login` component without doing try/catch here. Only place needs to be try/catch if you go for this case